# How to hide bottom navigation bar in Youtube app?

Tags: youtube, customization

I want to hide *bottom navigation bar* (not system wide navigation bar) or at least make it act like Chrome toolbar which shows/hides itself on scroll. I am blank on this as I couldn't find anything on hiding [Bottom Navigation bar](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#), except through programmatically.

This is what I'm talking about.

[image: IMG: Bottom Navigation bar]

I'm using a rooted OnePlus 6 with stock Android 8.1 and Xposed Framework.

As for reason for wanting this: I'd prefer to have real screen estate show something dynamic from Youtube, as part of scrolling content. That bar is in my way of using view to its maximum size.

Comment: How about changing per app dpi using app settings Xposed so that you get more to see (which is your ultimate aim)?

Comment: @beeshyams That would kill the taste of the UI I'm accustomed to. My point is that I find that bar unnecessary and I want to get rid of it, no matter how large my screen size is or how dense I can make it. It kind of bothers me, it being sitting there, doing nothing useful for me.

Comment: In which case, opening a request on Github /XDA to change it to 3 dots or add a setting to toggle may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xposed module [L Tweaks](https://repo.xposed.info/module/li.lingfeng.ltweaks) supports the feature of removing the bottom navigation bar of Youtube and several other apps.

1. Install L Tweaks. After installing the module, open it, then click Google.

   [image: IMG:]
2. Google apps are listed with features that L Tweaks can enable/disable. Go to the bottom to find Youtube. Enable `Remove bottom bar`

   [image: IMG:]
3. Before opening Youtube, force stop it. Open Youtube, the bottom navigation bar will no longer be shown.

   [image: IMG:]
4. To access `Home`, `Trending`, and other options, swipe from the left as you do for Google .Play

   [image: IMG:]

The module is also available in [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=li.lingfeng.ltweaks) and has other features.

**Note:** The device must be rooted, and have Xposed framework installed to use the module correctly.

**Disclaimer:** I am not related to the app's developer; I am just a user.

Answer (score -1):

**Not possible.** There isn't yet any applications or xposed modules that can do that. I also researched regarding this.

Comment: I clearly wrote in the bounty message that *I'm looking for a detailed and a working answer* This is neither detailed nor working for that matter.